# student cdf and normal ppf precision

Tags: scipy, python-3.7, precision, scipy.stats

Is there a way to increase the precision for the scipy.stats functions norm.pdf and t.cdf? Because if I do this it works:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, t
norm.ppf(t.cdf(9, 140))
```

but if I do the following, I got "inf" for the pdf and "1.0" for the cdf:

```
norm.ppf(t.cdf(10, 140))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok so no solution to this! Seems like the limit is about 8.2 (8.2sigma in fact). So if we want to know the detection level >8.2sigma, let's say a detection at 35sigma for instance, it is not possible :-/

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, the CDF in your example is not distinguishable from `1.0` with 64-bit floating point numbers. But if you want to know how close to `1.0` it is, you can compute the "survival function", which is the complement of the CDF.

```py
from scipy import stats
dist = stats.t(140)
dist.sf(10)  2.1240715308683204e-18
# The CDF is ~2.124e-18 less than 1.0
```

Instead of the `ppf` (the inverse of the `cdf`), you can use `isf` ("inverse survival function"):

```py
dist.isf(dist.sf(10))  # 10.000000000000007
```

If using the survival function is unfamiliar, it may be more comfortable to use the fact that the distribution is symmetric about the origin.

```py
dist.cdf(-10)  2.1240715308683204e-18
dist.ppf(dist.cdf(-10))  # -10.000000000000007
```

This will get you a little further than 37.5 sigma for the normal distribution (further for `t` with finite degrees of freedom). After that, you are working with numbers smaller than what 64-bit floating point numbers can represent directly, but you can go much further if you are comfortable working with the log of the probability. LMK if you're interested and I can post more about that.